# How to make a String become one Number in lua script (Mine question IS not that simple)

Tags: lua, numbers, transform, tostring

I wanna know How to convert a number in one String,in lua script,but i know If do this

Var = 10 ,
then the "var" Will be equal to 10
But my question is not simple I mean Literally transform the number into a String but keep having its value

Example
Var = 10
So if I add 10 + 5 is equal to 15
And what i want is :
Var + 5 = 15
So the "var" despite being a String works as a number

(I want to do this because I can't pull my variable to be displayed in a message (Var) along with another message that will be between "Your number is:"

Comment: "Example Var = 10 So if I add 10 + 5 is equal to 15 And what i want is : Var + 5 = 15 So the "var" despite being a String works as a number" - this is already the case: Lua's arithmetic operators coerce types. `"10" + 5` is `15` in Lua. What is your question?

Comment: rather than painting a vague image with your current description, create an example block of code. Show how that code produces X but what you want is Y, be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite simple, just wrap your variable like this:

```
var x = tonumber(x)

print(type(x))

-- Output : number.
```

This converts string `x` representing a number in base b [2..36, default: 10] to a number, or nil if invalid; for base 10, it accepts full format (e.g. "1.5e6").